# Unable to write TCP response data to variable

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

The problem is [visibilty of object inside and  asynchronous calls to functions] of exported model.

```
 exports.send = function(socket, req, callback) {

  req.external_response = {};                      //  initialize empty object

  client.connect(socket.Port, socket.IPAddress, function() {
    client.write(req.query);
  });

  client.on('data', function(data, req) {                                   
    req.external_response = data.toString('utf8');// assign response to it
                                        // console.log(req.external_response); gives out response
  });

  client.on('close', function() {
    client.destroy();
    callback();
  });
};
```

after send finishes and callback is executed i still have

> req.external_response = {}

if I do

```
var tmp = "";
client.on('data', function(data) {
    tmp = data.toString('utf8');// assign response to it
                                // console.log(tmp); gives out 
  });
req.external_response = tmp;    // tmp 'undefined'
```

I tried various ways to get that data written into variable but no success so far, maybe there is something that I did not noticed/missed. any suggestions how can I write TCP response to a desired variable?

Comment: What if you put console.log of data in on('data') handler just for debug? Does it output coming data?

Comment: Yeah it does. All the problem is inside each client.on{tmp.data} created, after it finishes its job data is lost/erased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first snippet doesn't work probably because of variables conflict:

```
exports.send = function(socket, req, callback) {

  req.external_response = {};

  client.on('data', function(data, req2) {   // <----- req2 !!!
    req.external_response = ...
  });

  client.on('close', function() {
    console.log(req.external_response);
    client.destroy();
    callback();
  });

};
```

The second snippet:

```
var tmp = "";
client.on('data', function(data) {
    tmp = data.toString('utf8');// assign response to it
                                // console.log(tmp); gives out 
  });
req.external_response = tmp;
```

won't work because you assign `tmp` to `req.external_response` before the callback assigns data to it.

Comment: client.on'close' happens after response is accepted by client, remote server closes connection after this. Callback() is in this event because 'close' comes after 'data'-recieved. Not before, so it is more logically right to be in 'close' rather than in 'data'. Anyhow, callback() will do the same in 'data'

Comment: @EpiGen I don't know what you're talking about. I didn't say a single word about `close` event. The code you've shown us (second snippet) clearly assigns to `req.external_response` before `data` event has a chance to fire (it's outside of `data` and outside of `close` events). As for the first snippet: it's a variable conflict. You assign to a different object.

Comment: @EpiGen Because you've written `console.log(tmp);` inside `.on("data")`. While you assign to `req.external_response` outside of it (i.e. earlier). Are we still talking about the second snippet? Because I don't think it is hard to see. `tmp = data.toString('utf8');` happens **after** `req.external_response = tmp;`.

Comment: @EpiGen Cool. You should be fine with the first piece of code if you just rename `req` into `req2` as shown by the code above.

Comment: if I put assignment inside inside .on("data") the result is still the same. I started writing with asynchronous calls. So, yeah you are right. But the 'right way' of assigning does not do the needed

Comment: with req2 result is the same

Comment: @EpiGen It's highly unlikely. You probably don't follow what I've written. Show us exactly what you did. Plus where do you check `req.external_response`, i.e. how do you call `send`? Note that you don't pass `req` to `callback`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are what I tried to reach what I want: (no result in all of'em)

## 1

```
var assignData = function(source, destination){
destination = source.toString('utf8');
callback();
};

 client.on('data', function(data) {
assignData(data,req.external_response);
});
```

## 2

```
client.on('data', function(data) {
req.external_response = data.toString('utf8');
callback();
```

});

call to .send(socket, req, callback)

```
var req = {query:'0000000082&ServiceID=2355&QueryCode=8080'};
sender.send(req, {}, done);
```